# Non-Gaussian distribution in continuous learning with error

Tags: encryption, lwe, machine-learning

The [CLWE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.09595.pdf) problem (and [related](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=gXdOOeqRN8g#:%7E:text=The%20exact%20sense%20of%20cryptographic,Shortest%20Vector%20Problem%20(GapSVP).)) talks about the hardness of finding the secret key $\vec{s}$, given polynomially many samples $(\vec{a},t)$, where $\vec{a}$ is sampled from the normal distribution, and $t=\gamma \vec{a}\cdot\vec{s}+e \pmod{1}$, where $e$ is also sampled from the normal distribution.

Is the distribution of $\vec{a}$ key to the hardness of CLWE? For example, what if I chose $\vec{a}$ from a Laplacian distribution, or Poisson distribution? Can I make any statements on the hardness of the CLWE problem?

Related:

1. [LWE versus neural nets](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81956/lwe-versus-neural-nets)
2. [LWE with a binary matrix A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/100941/lwe-with-a-binary-matrix-a?rq=1&newreg=7891b8904b0047d48716f7ed7553b5ec)
3. [Is LWE easy when the matrix $A$ is sparse?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/100790/is-lwe-easy-when-the-matrix-a-is-sparse)